# How to handle UnsafeMutablePointer correctly

Tags: c, swift, memory, core-audio

I am a little confused. When do I have to call free and when destroy/dealloc? I am working on a short code snippet learning core audio. I thought if I call     `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>.alloc(size)` then I should call `destroy` & `dealloc`.
But if I use `malloc()` or `calloc()` I am supposed to call `free()`.

In this example from Learning Core Audio the following code snippet makes me wonder:

```
var asbds = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamBasicDescription>.alloc(Int(infoSize))
audioErr = AudioFileGetGlobalInfo(kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AvailableStreamDescriptionsForFormat,
                              UInt32(sizeof(fileTypeAndFormat.dynamicType)), &fileTypeAndFormat,
                              &infoSize, asbds)
```

Here I use `alloc`. To free up memory `free`is called.

```
free(asbds)
```

But why not

```
asbds.destroy(Int(infoSize))
asbds.dealloc(Int(infoSize))
```

which I would expect following the rule.

I would appreciate any help, because this makes my head spin. The documentation says I am responsible for destroying and dealloc so that part is clear, but in which way?

Answer (score 4):

See the [UnsafeMutablePointer Structure Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UnsafeMutablePointer_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/UnsafeMutablePointer/s:FSp14initializeFromuRd__s14CollectionTypexzWd__9Generator7Element_rFqd__T_).

> The pointer can be in one of the following states:
>
> - Memory is not allocated (for example, pointer is null, or memory has been deallocated previously).
> - Memory is allocated, but value has not been initialized.
> - Memory is allocated and value is initialized.

You can use the pointed region safely when "allocated and initialized".
So, if you want to use Swift's `UnsafeMutablePointer` correctly, you need 2 steps before using and 2 steps after using.

(1) Allocate: `alloc(_:)`.

(2) Initilize: `initialize...()`

You can safely use the allocated and initialized region here.

(3) Deinitialize: `destroy(_:)`

(4) Deallocate: `dealloc(_:)`

---

And why you can use `free()` for `alloc(_:)`ed memory, that's because Swift uses `malloc(_:)` in the current implementation of `alloc(_:)`. So, using free means that your app depends on the current implementation of the Swift runtime.

---

So, using `UnsafeMutablePointer` is sort of difficult and annoying. You should consider passing an array as a pointer.
In your case, you can write something like this:

```
    let elementCount = Int(infoSize) / strideof(AudioStreamBasicDescription)
    var asbds: [AudioStreamBasicDescription] = Array(count: elementCount, repeatedValue: AudioStreamBasicDescription())
    audioErr = AudioFileGetGlobalInfo(kAudioFileGlobalInfo_AvailableStreamDescriptionsForFormat,
                                  UInt32(sizeof(fileTypeAndFormat.dynamicType)), &fileTypeAndFormat,
                                  &infoSize, &asbds)
```

(I think you should use this `elementCount` even when using `UnsafeMutablePointer`. `alloc(_:)` or `dealloc(_:)` uses "number of elements", not "byte size".)

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped a lot. I really like the array approach, that makes things much more swift-like.
But to get the `free()`part cleared for me. Right now there is no difference in calling `free`or `destroy`and `dealloc`? Did I understand that correct? Because `alloc` is calling `malloc` behind the curtains.