# Swift deallocate vs free usage

Tags: swift, unsafemutablepointer

I am allocating bytes using the following call in Swift 3:

```
let wordSize = 2
let numbytes = 1024*wordsize
var ptr = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: numbytes, alignedTo: wordSize)
```

Question is whether it is correct to deallocate the memory, are both these calls one and the same, or I should be using one over the other?

```
  free(ptr) // opt 1

  ptr.deallocate(bytes: numbytes, alignedTo: wordSize) //opt 2
```

Comment: Compare [How to handle UnsafeMutablePointer correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38175870/2976878). You should use `deallocate` – `free` may work, but that relies on an implementation detail of the Swift runtime.

Comment: I have edited out the [swift3] tag (again) – as it is only for questions *directly* related to changes in the language for that version, which yours is not. This is evident by the fact that it is (more or less) answered by the above linked Q&A, which was for Swift 2.

Comment: @Hamish this question uses Swift 3 syntax. As I noted in my answer, there is an appropriate answer in Swift 4 with different syntax. Does that affect your decision to remove the language version from the tags? I'm just curious; I really don't care what this question is tagged

Comment: @BenLeggiero The version specific tags are only meant to be used for questions specifically about changes in the language for that particular version (as stated in their tag wikis), not just questions about code using that version. I used to edit quite a lot of questions to remove incorrectly used version tags, but ultimately gave up as they're too frequently misused.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4 changed this signature to [`deallocate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/2949656-deallocate), making it much easier to decide when compared to `free(_:)`.

As [Hamish pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43717988/3939277#comment74479310_43717988), **`deallocate` is the preferred way to deallocate unsafe pointers in Swift**, a fact which is reinforced by the API designers placing this function *on* the type and documenting it, whereas `free(_:)` is global-scope (rarely appropriate in Swift) and undocumented.

#### Edit 2024-03-09

I should point out that it goes a little bit deeper than that.

`.deallocate()` is a Swift language function, whereas
`free(_:)` is a C/UNIX/POSIX function.

This means that the Swift language maintainers can improve `.deallocate()` if needed <sub>(for example, making a throwing version in case some problem occurred, or improving performance in memory-constrained environments, having specialized variants for certain types of pointers, etc.)</sub>,
whereas `free(_:)` is an OS-level call with some restrictions on how it can be implemented.

On that note, `free(_:)` actually *is* documented, but just like other UNIX/POSIX calls, that documentation isn't included in Swift docs. [The `free(_:)` documentation is in UNIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/free.html) (defined in [`stdlib.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdlib.h.html)), and includes the following:

> ##### NAME
>
> free - free allocated memory
>
> ##### SYNOPSIS
>
> ```c
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```
>
> ##### DESCRIPTION
>
> > [[CX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#CX)] ⌦ The functionality described on this reference page is aligned with the ISO C standard. Any conflict between the requirements described here and the ISO C standard is unintentional. This volume of POSIX.1-2017 defers to the ISO C standard. ⌫
>
> The *free()* function shall cause the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated; that is, made available for further allocation. If *ptr* is a null pointer, no action shall occur. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a function in POSIX.1-2017 that allocates memory as if by [*malloc()*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html), or if the space has been deallocated by a call to *free()* or [*realloc()*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html), the behavior is undefined.
>
> Any use of a pointer that refers to freed space results in undefined behavior.
>
> ##### RETURN VALUE
>
> The *free()* function shall not return a value.
>
> ##### ERRORS
>
> No errors are defined.

So you see there's a lot of specific restrictions on what `free(_:)` can do, meaning you can call it in Swift because Swift cn call any low-level function, but its specific requirements mean that Swift's version `.deallocate()` is more likely to be the correct choice for use in Swift